# std::copy to copy an array of doubles to an array of floats?

Tags: c++, copy, std

I'm working with a very disjointed API that has me bridging a lot of gaps between its own internal types.

In several places I am using std::copy to promote arrays of floats to arrays of doubles, or demote from arrays of doubles to arrays of floats to shuttle things between some of its more inconsistent objects.

Question is:
**Is that still considered the safest and closet-to-optimal way to do it, or are there recommended alternatives I should consider?**

In case it helps if there are some platform specific ones, the following is the platform case:
**Deployment is internal and very limited, only gcc 4.8, only Linux, very local and controlled use. I can consider "dangerous" platform specific alternatives that might be undefined on other platforms if they are worth it in terms of performance.**

Size of copies varies between a handful of triplets to, rarely, thousands of entries in one or two arrays. Length of source and targets are always the same, so simplest case for a copy possible, never ranged or conditional.

Comment: There seems to be no question (aside from the rather unclear one in the headline) - just a bunch of statements of what you are currently doing... What is your actual question? [Edit your question, don't add a comment]

Comment: I guess it gets lost in the details of my case. Bolded and prefaced the actual question.

Comment: Sounds OK to me, hard to answer more authoritatively without seeing real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is perfectly fine, and will have close to optimal performance.  If you really want to squeeze every drop of performance, you might need to write some SSE code by hand (e.g. using `CVTPD2PS`), but I wouldn't bother unless profiling shows these conversions to be a hot spot in your application.

Comment: It's not overly slow, but it's a relatively good chunk of the cycles in the cases with the larger arrays as they get moved (by the afore mentioned API) a lot and often little is done to those. I think we have full coverage on the floor with AVX, I should probably at least time a version unrolled by 4s using 4DPs to float. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: A modern, good compiler, should translate the loop to vector instructions, especially if the size is fixed when calling std::copy.